# Can a 3way switch provide a constant hot line to another unrelated load or switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, load

I had some electrical work done but we were unable to test the lines and now the electrician is gone.  To simplify the problem, we have two electrical boxes and two loads. One load (INSIDE LIGHT) will be controlled by the 3-way switches and the other (OUTSIDE LIGHT) by a separate switch.  The problem I see, or am not understanding, is the box with the OUTSIDE LIGHT has no actively hot lines yet.  Will the 3-way switch in that box have a line that is always hot once wired that I can use?

**I UPDATED PICTURE**

[image: diagram for standard 3 way switch]

[image: UPDATED what I have note 3 wires between boxes]

Comment: Are you OK with foreclosing the ability to have a 4-way switch for these lights, and how many wires are in the cable running between the two switch boxes?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand your question.  The lines shown are single black or white lines.   I only need to control the inside light by either the boxes.  I purchased two 3 way switches for the inside light  and one regular switch for the outside light. It appears I only have two lines (one black one white between the boxes)

Comment: I updated my image

Comment: oops my bad, I actually have 3 cables between boxes.. White, Black and Red. Updated image of what I have.

Comment: Is re-running the cable between the two switch-boxes an option?

Comment: It's romex, ideally would rather not.  I have an outlet that live about 6 feet away on the same wall I could string a line from, but was hoping I did not have to. Surprised this is so wrong. I wonder what the electrician was thinking. but wait I have 3 lines and specs say I only need two for the travelers.Can't I just use the red as hot?

Comment: You need two travelers + a *neutral* (white) and a *ground* (bare)...so you're out of wires in that cable

Comment: Is that nearby outlet on a general lighting circuit?

Answer (score 2):

When you're using old style steam switches, 3-way circuits look like this.

[image]

*Yellow=travelers, red=switched-hot.*

Notice that there are 2 travelers, and the remote 3-way is lucky if the third wire is neutral.  There's no question of bringing always-hot along with the travelers; there simply isn't a 4th conductor in the cable.   (And you can't use ground).

### Smart switches instead

In this setup, wires 9 and 7/2 are always-hot.  Wires 10, 8/1, 6 and 5 are neutral.  OK, we got hot and neutral to the far box.

To switch the outside light, you put a plain switch between always-hot 2 and switched-hot 4.

To switch the inside light, we get a 3-way "smart switch".   It hooks up as follows:

- Neutral to 1/5/6.
- Always-hot (LINE) to 2.
- Switched-hot (LOAD) to 3.
- Traveler (if needed) to 11.

Oh wait, you wanted 3-way control.  OK, we also put a smart switch "remote" in the other box.  It gets:

- Neutral to 10/8
- always-hot to 9/7
- If needed, traveler to 12.

All grounds get spiderwebbed to each other.

Comment: Thank you!!! in your explaination doe Leviton 3 way switches qualify as smart switch "remote" ?  A plain swtich has two terminals.  My 3 ways swtiches have a copper lead on the left and copper lead on the right top and black lead on the right bottom.  Sorry, but can you explain how to wire to switches?

Comment: You have specs/links to these "smart" switches?

Comment: search of Smart 3-way switch pulls up switches with Wifi,, Is that what you mean and what if wifi is down, do they still work?

Comment: @Hell.Bent the switch you describe is a plain old steam-era 3-way, and the brass screws are for the travelers as in the first diagram.  Some smart switches are able to use a plain switch as a remote, using 1 traveler, which would suffice here.  There is a universe of these products and we are not a shopping assistance site. Some use WiFi and others use proprietary protocols or use powerline signaling, Insteon is but one example.  Others use 1 traveler, which you happen to have spare!

Comment: @FreeMan quite right, I updated the drawing and forgot to check the text!